# Can the prepare phase be omitted in a pbft-based block chain?

Tags: blockchain, consensus, cryptocurrency

https://docs.icon.foundation/ICON-Whitepaper-EN-Draft.pdf
On page 23 of this paper, they insist that prepare phase can be omitted in the pbft consensus. This is confusing because it is different from the existing pbft. 
Although a proposer propagates different blocks to each nodes, fork will not occur unless a node signs twice. Generally I agree with their arguments. If this is possible, pbft can be faster. But I want to hear from other pbft experts. Why is the prepare phase required in PBFT? And can it be omitted?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually read the paper you linked, but I think I can answer your question from your last sentence;

> "Why is the prepare phase required in PBFT?"

You may know that there is pre-prepare phase in PBFT. Pre-prepare phase is the first step of PBFT's three phase consensus protocol, and in this phase, primary assigns a unique sequence number to the client's request. PBFT is for Byzantine fault tolerant algorithm, meaning that primary can be malicious; For example, primary in pre-prepare phase can assign different sequence number to the same request, thereby violating safety condition. To detect this kind of faulty behavior of primary, replicas need to exchange pre-prepare message in the next step(prepare phase) to check that they all received exactly same message from the primary. To conclude, prepare phased is required to verify the primary's message by replicas. I recommend [BGP(Byzantine General Problem)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs174/byzantine.pdf) for more details.

And your second question is...

> And can it be omitted?

The answer is "no". As explained earlier, if the protocol omits the prepare phase, it doesn't tolerate Byzantine faulty primary.